# Image Accordion controlled by scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I need to create an image accordion where it will be controlled by page scroll, like when you scroll your page and the accordion start it start to open and close horizontally while you still 'scrolling down' the page, after all, images open it continues to scroll vertically the page.

on the image you can see like when you scroll down the images should open one by one until finish.

If anyone has a solution for that and could share. Thanks!

[The accordion should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IelfC.jpg)

Comment: Hello, this isn't a code-assignment solution website but this is where you got the reason why for the question.

Comment: Please add more details,or executable code to know were ur stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with `slick.js` https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ it's open source and has custom events. Here is working codepen demo: https://codepen.io/webisora/pen/EwQoMR